# Taking reference of html elements in protractor testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I am testing an angular app in Protractor.And I am tying to access the elements of an html form.

I have this label in my form:

```html
 <label  #name   class="form-control-label" id='#name'  for="field_nombre" >Nombre</label>
```

And this componnet that calls the url of the template like this:

```html
   template: require('./paciente-dialog.component.html'),
```

Now the url of the app when I go to this html form is `'http://localhost:8080/#/paciente'`

So I create this po.ts file which takes me to this url and want to output the label that I have:

```html
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('http://localhost:8080/#/paciente');
  }

  getParagraphText() {
    //return element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText();
    return element(by.css('#name')).getInnerHtml;
  }
}
```

```html
import { AppPage } from './app.po';


describe('Second  Test', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });
  it('should display welcome message', () => {


    page.navigateTo();

    console.log('This is the label'+ page.getParagraphText() );

    }
```

Now it prints undefined instead of teh label name. I do teh same in jasmine testing and it works. Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Protractor can act and react a little differently compared to Jasmine. Try it this way:

**HTML** (note the id attribute without the hash)

```
<label  #name  class="form-control-label" id="name"  for="field_nombre" >Nombre</label>
```

**AppPagePO**

```
import { ElementFinder, browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

getParagraphText(): ElementFinder {
    return element(by.id(name));
}
```

**Test**

```
page.getParagraphText().getAttribute('value').then( text => {
    console.log('This is the label ' + text);
});
```

Comment: It says name is not defined. I think it is a problem of routes. Cause it doesnt know which name to reference.

Comment: Actually what route sould I put in the navigate methd? I have put the route that I see in my browser when I deploy my app. So how should it know what form it should refer to?I jasmine I reference the componnet for example and work with componnet objects

Comment: I posted you an example containing all the important files and facts. Please work through it. Maybe it's just a small piece in the puzzle you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss something I can't see as your example is shortened. Here is a complete example containing all the necessary stuff you need for a single test.

I have an imaginary component foo, located in the folder foo. In this folder I also have the PO-file.

**Foo Component**  (symbolic folder structure)

- foo.component.ts
- foo.component.css
- foo.component.html
- **foo.component.po.ts**

**foo.component.html**

Contains the label we're talking about

```
<label  #name  class="form-control-label" id="foo-name"  for="field_nombre" >Nombre</label>
...
<label  #age  class="form-control-label" id="foo-age"  for="field_edad" >Edad</label>
```

**foo.component.po.ts**

The constants are substitutes for the id-fields of the elements in the HTML-Templates.

```
import { ElementFinder, element, by, browser } from 'protractor';

const nameInputField = 'foo-name';
const ageInputField = 'foo-age';

export class FooComponentPO {

    getNameInputField(): ElemenFinder {
        return element(by.id(nameInputField));
    }

    // just for the example
    getAgeInputField(): ElemenFinder {
        return element(by.id(ageInputField));
    }

}
```

**foo.test.e2e.ts** (located somewhere else in your directory hierarchy)

Import your PO-File in your Testfile and create a local instance of it. Then use it in your tests. That's exactly how I do this every day.

```
import { FooComponentPO } from '../../src/app/components/foo/foo.component.po.ts';
import { ElementFinder, element, by, browser } from 'protractor';

const fooComponentPO = new FooComponentPO();

it('calls the browser-link', () => {
    page.navigateTo(); // this is your call.

    // now the browser needs a while until the page is build up.
    // wait some time
    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.sleep(2000);
});

// Now give it a try
it('should contain the text foo', () => {

     fooComponentPO.getNameInputField().getAttribute('value').then( text => {
         console.log('This is the label ' + text);
         expect<any>(text).toContain('foo');
     });

});
```

Comment: I want to reference the label. Aren't you printing the value of your constant here that is exactly 'name' or why are you initializing it to name?

Comment: How do you now that it reference the same label from this HTML form and not from another one?

Comment: No, you actually reference the label. I renamed the id-field to make that clear.  Your second question is easy to answer. You can't know that from the standpoint of the PO-file or the testing framework. This is, and don't get this wrong, your job. You have to choose absolutely unique IDs.

Comment: In my company, we make sure that an id never repeats by giving it the component's name as a prefix and adding the type if necessary. For example: foo-component-customer-name-label or foo-component-customer-address-input. Then you can be sure that this field is unique across your app. -- I'd really recommend you to think about a good id scheme, because when it comes to testing you'll need unique ids everywhere and you'll struggle pretty soon whenever ids repeat.

Comment: If this helped you a bit I'd really appreciate if you could mark one of my answers as solution.

Comment: I mean sure I have different IDs, but since it is saying undefined, maybe it is not referencing to the html form. Is there a way to know?  I JASMINE you know that because you put a component reference in your testbed that belongs to this componnet. And it references only the HTMLs that belong to this componnet. Meanwhile here we have no html form referenced. Maybe the right navigation would help.

Comment: Sure but I gotta verif that it works like this. Until now it says name undefined

Comment: Then, please take the developer tools of your browser and analyze the HTML-DOM of your page. Have a look at the id-tag of the label. -- Usually you can force protractor to open the browser while testing. Then you should see whether you're on the right page. Maybe you're just to fast. Testing with protractor means always to wait for angular or the browser. I added another method to my example above. `'calls the browser-link'` Please, have a look at it.

Comment: But the browser closes itself after one second.

Comment: Sorry, but this must have something to do with your protractor setup. What about the test? Does it perform as expected now?

Comment: Hi, I think I now what the last problem is that you have to put aside. Remove the `beforeEach()` method! Instantiate `page`only once  by `const  page = new AppPage();` as I did in my example with `fooComponentPO`.